# Closed analytic subvariety of $\mathbb C^n$ not defined by global holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-geometry

Here is the motivation of this question: $\mathbb C^n$ is already "local" in algebraic category. In other words, algebraic subvarieties of $\mathbb C^n$ are affine, so they are common zero locus of finitely many polynomials defined on $\mathbb C^n$.

However, $\mathbb C^n$ is not "local" enough for analytic varieties, since by definition (Griffiths & Harris, page 12), an analytic subvariety $X$ of $\mathbb C^n$ is that for each $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb C^n$, such that $X\cap U$ is common zero loci of holomorphic functions $f_1,...,f_k$ defined on $U$.

Of course, globally defined holomorphic functions will do the job, for example, the graph of the entire function $z\mapsto e^z$ produces the simplest analytic subvariety of $\mathbb C^2$ that is not algebraic. However, is there an example of a closed analytic subvariety of $\mathbb C^n$ *not* defined by global holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^n$?

Comment: I think that you need to be more careful with a definition of analytic subvariety, otherwise a zero set of a function holomorphic in some domain is an example.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin Thanks, I think the example I'm looking for is unbounded, so I added closedness assumption.

Answer (score 3):

A closed subset $X$ of $C^n$ satisfying your definition can be defined by global analytic functions. This follows from the solution of the "Second Cousin problem" in $C^n$, and is explained in any text on functions of several complex variables.

Comment: Thank you. Vaninghing of $H^1(\mathbb C^n,\mathcal{O})$ implies gluing divisors on $\mathbb C^n$ has no obstruction. This solve the problem when $X$ is codimension one, but I don't see how the why general case follows from it.

Comment: @AGlearner You need Cartan's B theorem for arbitrary codimension.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin Sorry, it should be $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$ controls the divisor (instead of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ as I wrote). However, $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ is not a coherent sheaf anymore since it is not even a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, so I guess we cannot apply Cartan B here. But I should thank for your suggestion since it brought me to the fact that "$X$ being closed analytic subvariety of $\mathbb C^n$ implies $X$ is a stein space".

Comment: Dear @OlegEroshkin, if I apply Cartan's theorem A to the ideal sheaf $I_X$ on $\mathbb C^n$, there are finitely many global sections $s_1,...,s_k\in H^0(\mathbb C^n, I_X)$ which induce the finite generation $\oplus_{i=1}^k\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C^n}\twoheadrightarrow I_X$. Therefore, as globally holomorphic functions, $\{s_1=0,...,s_k=0\}$ defines $X$. Do you think this is correct? Also, could you explain a little bit about your suggestion on applying Cartan B? Thanks!

Comment: That was my thinking. But, unless I am mistaken, you will get finite generation only over the arbitrary compact. I think, that over $\mathbb{C}^n$, the ideal sheaf may not be finitely generated. The idea: take a union of varieties, which required at least $k$ functions to define. By translating varieties, we may enforce that the union is locally finite. Then the union is an analytic set. To avoid such issues, you may consider an irreducible analytic set.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin: I see, thanks for pointing that out. So in general a closed analytic subset $X$ of $\mathbb C^n$ is supposedly common zero loci of countably many globally holomorphic functions (by choosing a countable open covers). But if we require additionally that $X$ is irreducible, do you think the ideal sheaf $I_X$ can be (globally) finitely generated? Or do you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there is a not finitely generated irreducible analytic set. However, it's not obvious to me how to prove that for an irreducible analytic set, the ideal sheaf is finitely generated.